# CPU measures (Cache misses/hits) which do not make sense

Tags: c++, caching, cpu, performancecounter, cpu-cache

I use [Intel PCM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor) for fine-grained CPU measurements. In my code, I am trying to measure the cache efficiency.

Basically, I first put a small array into the L1 cache (by traversing it many times), then I fire up the timer, go over the array one more time (which hopefully uses the cache), and then turning off the timer.

PCM shows me that I have a rather high L2 and L3 miss ratio. I also checked with  `rdtscp` and the cycles per array operation is 15 (which is much higher than 4-5 cycles for accessing L1 cache).

What I would expect is that the array is placed entirely in L1 cache, and I wouldn't have high L1, L2 and L3 miss ratio.

My system has 32K, 256K and 25M for L1, L2 and L3 respectively. 
Here's my code:

```
static const int ARRAY_SIZE = 16;

struct MyStruct {
    struct MyStruct *next;
    long int pad;
}; // each MyStruct is 16 bytes

int main() {
    PCM * m = PCM::getInstance();
    PCM::ErrorCode returnResult = m->program(PCM::DEFAULT_EVENTS, NULL);
    if (returnResult != PCM::Success){
        std::cerr << "Intel's PCM couldn't start" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    MyStruct *myS = new MyStruct[ARRAY_SIZE];

    // Make a sequential liked list,
    for (int i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE - 1; i++){
        myS[i].next = &myS[i + 1];
        myS[i].pad = (long int) i;
    }
    myS[ARRAY_SIZE - 1].next = NULL;
    myS[ARRAY_SIZE - 1].pad = (long int) (ARRAY_SIZE - 1);

    // Filling the cache
    MyStruct *current;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++){
        current = &myS[0];
        while ((current = current->n) != NULL)
            current->pad += 1;
    }

    // Sequential access experiment
    current = &myS[0];
    long sum = 0;

    SystemCounterState before = getSystemCounterState();

    while ((current = current->n) != NULL) {
        sum += current->pad;
    }

    SystemCounterState after = getSystemCounterState();

    cout << "Instructions per clock: " << getIPC(before, after) << endl;
    cout << "Cycles per op: " << getCycles(before, after) / ARRAY_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "L2 Misses:     " << getL2CacheMisses(before, after) << endl;
    cout << "L2 Hits:       " << getL2CacheHits(before, after) << endl; 
    cout << "L2 hit ratio:  " << getL2CacheHitRatio(before, after) << endl;
    cout << "L3 Misses:     " << getL3CacheMisses(before_sstate,after_sstate) << endl;
    cout << "L3 Hits:       " << getL3CacheHits(before, after) << endl;
    cout << "L3 hit ratio:  " << getL3CacheHitRatio(before, after) << endl;

    cout << "Sum:   " << sum << endl;
    m->cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Instructions per clock: 0.408456
Cycles per op:        553074
L2 Cache Misses:      58775
L2 Cache Hits:        11371
L2 cache hit ratio:   0.162105
L3 Cache Misses:      24164
L3 Cache Hits:        34611
L3 cache hit ratio:   0.588873
```

---

**EDIT**:
I also checked the following code, and still get the same miss ratios (which I would have expected to get almost zero miss ratios):

```
SystemCounterState before = getSystemCounterState();
// this is just a comment
SystemCounterState after = getSystemCounterState();
```

---

**EDIT 2**: As one commented suggested, these results might be due to the overhead of the profiler itself. So I instead of only one time, I changed the code traverse the array many times (200,000,000 times), to amortize the profiler's overhead. I still get very low L2 and L3 Cache ratios (%15).

Comment: Your experiment (the while loop that is measured) has only 16 iterations. Probably the overhead and perturbation of the getSystemCounterState function dominates the measurements.

Comment: I would recommend to compare L2/LLC miss/hits with L1 hit counters. You might find that you have few M L1 hits vs. 50K L2 misses.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you get l2 and l3 misses from all cores on your system

I look at the PCM implementation here: https://github.com/erikarn/intel-pcm/blob/ecc0cf608dfd9366f4d2d9fa48dc821af1c26f33/src/cpucounters.cpp

[1] in the implementation of `PCM::program()` on line 1407 I don't see any code that limits events to a specific process

[2] in the implementation of `PCM::getSystemCounterState()` on line 2809 you can see that the events are gathered from all cores on your system. So I would try to set cpu affinity of the process to one core and then only read events from this core - with this function `CoreCounterState getCoreCounterState(uint32 core)`

Comment: That's correct - PCM by default gets information from all cores on your system.