# Is it possible to use Linux Perf profiler inside C++ code?

Tags: c++, linux, performancecounter, cpu-cache, perf

I would like to measure L1, L2 and L3 Cache hit/miss ratio of some parts of my C++ code. I am not interested to use Perf for my entire application. Can Perf be used as a library inside C++?

```
int main() {
    ...
    ...
    start_profiling()
    // The part I'm interested in
    ...
    end_profiling()
    ...
    ...
}
```

I gave Intel PCM a shot, but I had two issues with it. First, it [gave me some strange numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270741/cpu-measures-cache-misses-hits-which-do-not-make-sense). Second, it doesn't support L1 Cache profiling.

If it's not possible with Perf, what is the easiest way to get that information?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like all you're trying to do is read a few perf counters, something that the [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/) library is ideal for.

[Example.](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/performance-monitoring-with-papi/184406109)

The [full list of supported counters](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projects/papi/wiki/PAPIC:PAPI_presets.3) is quite long, but it sounds like you're most interested in `PAPI_L1_TCM`, `PAPI_L1_TCA`, and their `L2` and `L3` counterparts. Note that you can also break down the accesses into reads/writes, and you can distinguish instruction and data caches.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is special per-thread monitoring which allows to read perf counters from within userspace. See manual page for [`perf_event_open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html)

Since `perf` supports only L1i, L1d, and last-level cache events, you'll need to use `PERF_EVENT_RAW` mode and use numbers from manual onto your CPU.

To implement a profiling, you'll need to setup `sample_interval`, `poll`/`select` fd or wait for `SIGIO` signal, and when it happens, read sample and instruction pointer from it. You'll may latter try to resolve returned instruction pointers to a function names using a debugger like GDB.

---

Another option is to use [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/). You'll need empty implementation of `start|end_profiling()`, just to enable SystemTap profiling with something like that:

```
global traceme, prof;

probe process("/path/to/your/executable").function("start_profiling") {
    traceme = 1;
}

probe process("/path/to/your/executable").function("end_profiling") {
    traceme = 0;
}

probe perf.type(4).config(/* RAW value of perf event */).sample(10000) {
    prof[usymname(uaddr())] <<< 1;
}

probe end {
    foreach([sym+] in prof) {
        printf("%16s %d\n", sym, @count(prof[sym]));
    }
}
```